# add a condition to the lambda for each expression in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

Basically I want to do this

```
foreach (var TA in TheToAddresses)
{
    if(TA.ToLower () != "a@a.com")
    {
        _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA);
    }
}
```

how do I modify 
this line to include the condition as well?
Thanks

```
TheToAddresses.ForEach(TA => _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA));
```

Comment: What is the type of `_message.ToRecipients`? There may well be a nicer solution without `ForEach`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TheToAddresses.Where(address => address.ToLower() != "a@a.com").ToList().ForEach(TA => _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
TheToAddresses.ForEach(TA => 
{
  if(TA.ToLower () != "a@a.com")
     _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA) 
});
```

If `ToRecipients` is of type `List` you can write:

```
_message.ToRecipients.AddRange(TheToAddresses.Where(TA => TA.ToLower() != "a@a.com"));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can write a multi-line lambda method by wrapping it with { }:

```
TheToAddresses.ForEach(TA =>
    {
        if(TA.ToLower () != "a@a.com")
        {
             _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA);
        }
     });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
TheToAddresses.Where(r=> r.ToLower () != "a@a.com").ToList()
.ForEach(TA => _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA));
```

Comment: `IEnumerable` doesn't contain `ForEach` extension method in LINQ namespace by default. Only `List` has such a method.

Comment: That's true, but TheToAddresses is a List, because Ienumerable has no Add method, that is a method of IList interface

Comment: Yes, but `Where` returns `IEnumerable`, not `List`.

Comment: @It will work. and it is valid solution. But, it consumes more time and memory (additional iteration for creating new list and memory needed for allocating it).

Comment: Hmm we have to choose between readability and performance. I think this is more readable then the version with inner condition and usually the iterated list are not so huge in memory so there should be no significant difference

Comment: I don't consider multi-line lambda (when lines count <= 3, let's say) irreadable :)  But it is opinion based, so there no reason for further discussion :)

Answer (score 0):

```
TheToAddresses.Where(ta => ta.ToLower() != "a@a.com")
              .ForEach(TA => _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA));
```

Comment: The same as problem as in other anwser - `Where`  returns `IEnumerable`. There is no extension method in Linq namesapce called `ForEach`.

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is nearly the right way. LINQ shouldn't have side-effects. See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/05/18/foreach-vs-foreach.aspx

```
foreach (var TA in TheToAddresses)
{
    if(!StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Equals(TA, "a@a.com"))
    {
        _message.ToRecipients.Add(TA);
    }
}
```

The only point is that if you want to do case insensitive comparisons you don't `ToLower()`/`ToUpper()` (see http://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/, beginning with *Strings are where it really starts to get hairy*)